# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error:

> - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './salt/ghost' to './salt/#sql2-4ab-630b' (errno: 152). Failing Query:
>     "ALTER TABLE ghost DROP FOREIGN KEY ghost.row_id"

I looked for some information but I didn't get a solution..any help?

This is my DDL:

```
ghost,"CREATE TABLE `ghost` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `packet_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tbl_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_id2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_value` mediumblob,
  `new_value` mediumblob,
  `ghost_action` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ghost_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ghost_action_comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ghost_status_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `ghost_status_comments` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `serialized` mediumblob,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_change_1_idx` (`ghost_user_id`),
  KEY `fk_change_2_idx` (`ghost_status_id`),
  KEY `row_id2_idx` (`row_id2`),
  CONSTRAINT `ghost_ghost_status_id_ghost_status_id` FOREIGN KEY (`ghost_status_id`) REFERENCES `ghost_status` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ghost_ghost_user_id_sf_guard_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`ghost_user_id`) REFERENCES `sf_guard_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=120450 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"
```

Javi

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your DDL, I did find this on the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-error-codes.html) regarding error code 1025, in one of the user comments:

> To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than the column name of the foreign key.

So, instead of dropping the `ghost.row_id` column, try dropping the foreign key using the FK name.

Comment: Thanks DTest, could you tell what is the FK name?

Comment: @user248959 Err, you don't seem to have a foreign key for `row_id2`